# Modify Sails.js project structure

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'd like to have my project using the following structure :

```
|_ bin
|_ docs
|_ logs
|_ src
  |_main
    |_ api
    |_ config
    |_ views
    ...
    app.js
  |_test
|_ node_modules
|_ package.json
```

By default, the app.js is in the same directory as the npm modules, is it possible to do it my way? I modified the .sailsrc file to change the paths (especially for the adapters), but once I try to run the app, the sails module can't be found.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this. However in most cases it is more trouble than its worth.

Comment: I find my code more clear, my dependencies at the root, the sources, the tests, ... I prefer such a structure

Comment: I think you best bet is to build up your own framework and if you like stuff that sails does, just copy it over.

Comment: Agree with Meeker here, it would be easier to redo everything "from scratch" than to modify Sails like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to have my project using the following structure
>
> is it possible to do it my way?

No.

The solution is to to build your sails.js app the same way as the thousands of other sails.js applications. If you don't want to follow convention, you're on your own.